# Illegal argument exception in formatting Calendar object

Tags: java, android, calendar, simpledateformat

I have an object of calendar and I want to display it in this format: "year.month.day hour.min.sec TimeZone"

I have written following lines of code but last line throws IllegalArgumentException.

I have no idea where is my problem. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss Z");
String bookingDate = formatter.format(date);
```

==========

**Update**

==========

Log:

```
> 09-30 11:19:47.205: E/AndroidRuntime(19285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 09-30 11:19:47.205: E/AndroidRuntime(19285): Process:
> com.passenger, PID: 19285 09-30 11:19:47.205:
> E/AndroidRuntime(19285): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad
> class: class java.util.GregorianCalendar 09-30 11:19:47.205:
> E/AndroidRuntime(19285):  at
> java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:296) 09-30 11:19:47.205:
> E/AndroidRuntime(19285):  at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:93)
> 09-30 11:19:47.205: E/AndroidRuntime(19285):  at
> com.fragment.bookingdetail.BookingDetailFragment.sendDataToAP(BookingDetailFragment.java:1105)
> 09-30 11:19:47.205: E/AndroidRuntime(19285):  at
> com.fragment.bookingdetail.BookingDetailFragment.sendBookingToServer(BookingDetailFragment.java:782)
> 09-30 11:19:47.205: E/AndroidRuntime(19285):  at
> com.fragment.bookingdetail.BookingDetailFragment.onClick(BookingDetailFragment.java:340)
```

Comment: Post the exception message and stacktrace.

Comment: try to wrap Z as 'Z'

Comment: NOTE: SimpleDateFormat constructor takes second parameter Locale. `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Since I mentioned which and where exception is happening, Log might not be useful. Anyways, I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: @getlost, Sorry didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can't format a `Calendar` object with a `DateFormat`. Use `Calendar#getTime()` and pass the resulting `Date` object to the `format` call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
String bookingDate = formatter.format(date.getTime());
System.out.println(bookingDate);
```